# How do I change power settings on my laptop to hear audio while running on battery?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, power

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad with Windows 7.

I can hear sound when my laptop is powered up on AC power. While on battery power I can not hear streaming media, such as YouTube.

I was informed that I should change my power settings to be able to hear sound while watching videos on battery power. How do I do that?

Comment: Try `Fn + F3` to go to the settings.

Comment: Your model number would help. Have you tried adjusting the Lenovo Power Management settings for battery power?

Comment: Here is a Lenovo Thinkpad tutorial for [Using Power Manager in Windows® 7 Tutorial](http://training.lenovo.partner-management.com/et.cfm?&formState=LlRysy9LtMWU-rXeIsQdkjeihGP2xT4eX5w2rqm-o5SL_dQTzAFURMZBc-Gxc_rNI-0DTlsWwXxADX-bxVkfdonNF9HADfYuA_eu76hmLhuca3ZzpbK78DU724PF-LQ8h3OVggN8ETA-TM7qI12y8gO43gCKOjQ9sibwvDTgw_J2dhbCiTabKR1X4RSxqHS7kACrWlTzN3IHPaYXuM3Xaz_j02X6Fdha29vRD2YVtycQkyMf0R6p0rDYKu_AD_xnryXxdKfaMeLog10metRR1fCLgo188OzUeaAloGCsAJU|01&11832)